# How to update QtGui.QSlider's position while video goes on?

Tags: pyqt4, phonon

I am currently using PyQt4 to develop a video player GUI, and I use QtGui.QSlider to control the progress of video stream. And I am wondering how can I change the slider's value when video is playing?

```
import sys, os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon

class vidplayer(QtGui.QWidget):


def __init__(self,url,xml_url,parent = None):
    self.url = url
    super(vidplayer,self).__init__()
    self.initUI()
    self.getElm_from_XML(xml_url);


def printXMLInfo(self):
    itemlist = self.doc.getElementsByTagName('object')
    for item in itemlist:
        print ("frame-span:"+str(item.attributes['framespan'].value)+
        " Event tag: "+ str(item.attributes['name'].value));
    print(len(itemlist))


def getElm_from_XML(self,xml_url):
    self.doc = minidom.parse(xml_url)
    self.clipList = self.doc.getElementsByTagName('object');
    print("Reading XML done...\n Have read %s elements.\n" %(len(self.clipList)))


def initUI(self):
    ## create widgets
    # phonon video player and media
    self.vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
    media = Phonon.MediaSource(self.url)

    # layout components (boxes)
    self.vbox_play = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.hbox_ctrl_vid = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hbox_ctrl_dec = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.vbox_control = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    # bottons to control
    self.btn_go_prev = QtGui.QPushButton("|<")
    self.btn_go_next = QtGui.QPushButton(">|")
    self.btn_play = QtGui.QPushButton("Play(Pause)")
    self.btn_accept = QtGui.QPushButton("Accept")
    self.btn_reject = QtGui.QPushButton("Reject")

    # slider to interact with videoplayer
    self.sld = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,self)
    #self.sld = Phonon.SeekSlider(self)

    ## layout components setup
    self.vbox_control.addStretch(1)
    self.hbox_ctrl_vid.addStretch(1)
    self.hbox_ctrl_dec.addStretch(1)
    self.vbox_play.addStretch(1)
    self.hbox.addStretch(1)
    self.vbox_control.setDirection(QtGui.QBoxLayout.BottomToTop)
    self.vbox_play.setDirection(QtGui.QBoxLayout.BottomToTop)


    ## widgets inits
    self.vp.load(media)
    self.vp.play()

    self.sld.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
    self.sld.setRange(1,1000)


    ## widgets assignment
    self.hbox_ctrl_vid.addWidget(self.btn_go_prev)
    self.hbox_ctrl_vid.addWidget(self.btn_play)
    self.hbox_ctrl_vid.addWidget(self.btn_go_next)
    self.hbox_ctrl_dec.addWidget(self.btn_accept)
    self.hbox_ctrl_dec.addWidget(self.btn_reject)

    self.vbox_play.addWidget(self.vp)
    self.vbox_play.addWidget(self.sld)

    self.vbox_control.addLayout(self.hbox_ctrl_dec)
    self.vbox_control.addLayout(self.hbox_ctrl_vid)

    self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_play)
    self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_control)


    ## main setup and display
    self.setLayout(self.hbox)
    self.setGeometry(300,300,600,400)
    self.setWindowTitle('CCNY_SRI TRECVid iSED UI')
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./icon.png'))
    self.show()


    ## connection set up
    self.sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.sld_changeValue)
    self.vp.finished.connect(self.onReachingFinish)
    self.btn_play.clicked.connect(self.onClicked_play)
    self.btn_go_next.clicked.connect(self.onClicked_nextClip)
    self.btn_go_prev.clicked.connect(self.onClicked_prevClip)


###################### callable functions ##################
def sld_changeValue(self,value):
    totalT = self.vp.totalTime()
    print totalT
    newT = totalT*value/1000
    self.vp.seek(newT)

def onClicked_play(self):
    # BUG: sth wrong with boundary
    if self.vp.isPaused():
        self.vp.play()
        print("resume play")
    elif self.vp.isPlaying():
        self.vp.pause()
        print("pause at",self.sld.value())
    elif self.sld.value()<1000:
        self.vp.play()

def onClicked_nextClip(self):
    print("go next")

def onClicked_prevClip(self):
    print("go prev")

def onClicked_acc(self):
    print("accepted")

def onClicked_rej(self):
    print("rejected")

def onReachingFinish(self):
    self.vp.pause()
    self.vp.stop()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = vidplayer(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated class for that in Phonon: `Phonon.SeekSlider`:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # creating player resource
        self.player = Player()
        # adding controls
        self.sliders = Sliders(self.player)

class Sliders(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, player):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.seek_slider = Phonon.SeekSlider(player , self)

class Player(Phonon.MediaObject):
    def __init__(self):
        Phonon.MediaObject.__init__(self)
        self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory, self)
        self.path = Phonon.createPath(self, self.audioOutput)
```

This slider will directly pilot the play and its position will be updated during media playing. But, as that's a drawback I'm looking for a workaround, there is no `valueChanged` signal :-/